# Почему не работает пример из официальной документации Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Есть метод который обновляет одно поле `boolean` в таблице по `id`

```
@Override
public void updateDone(int id, boolean done) {

    try (final Session session = factory.get().openSession()) {

        String hql = "update Task set done = :newDone where id = :oldId";

        final int i = session.createQuery(hql)
                .setParameter("id", id)
                .setParameter("done", done)
                .executeUpdate();


        session.beginTransaction();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

Таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tasks (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    done BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    create_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Причем пример взят из официальной документации: [Example 405. UPDATE query statements](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-api)

Только там :

```
int updatedEntities = session.createQuery(
    "update Person " +
    "set name = :newName " +
    "where name = :oldName" )
.setParameter( "oldName", oldName )
.setParameter( "newName", newName )
.executeUpdate();
```

Просто Имя класса и полей поменял на свои остальное то же самое.

Падает вот такой Exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an
>   update/delete query   at
>   org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1496)
>     at ru.pravvich.dao.TaskDAO.updateDone(TaskDAO.java:69)

69 строка это вызов `.executeUpdate();`
И программа зависает на этом дальше не идет...

Помогите пожалуйста что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Транзакция должна начаться до выполнения запроса и должна быть зафиксирована после:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(hql)
                .setParameter("id", id)
                .setParameter("done", done);

Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
query.executeUpdate();
tx.commit();
```